# How to build a complex email layout with MJML(columns nested in columns)?

Tags: html, css, email, layout, mjml

I'm working on achieving this email look. I have tried using pure html in `mj-text` syntaxes but the html doesn't behave the same as normal html. I have decided to go with `mj-table` but the styling is not easy and I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Here is the result I want:

[image]

Here is what I got so far:

[image]

My code:

```
<mj-head>
        <mj-attributes>
            <mj-text padding="0" font-family="system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" color="#1d1d1f"/>
            <mj-section padding="0"/>
            <mj-wrapper padding="0" background-color="#fff" border-right="1px solid right"/>
            <mj-button padding="0"/>
            <mj-column padding="0"/>
            <mj-image padding="0"/>
            <mj-table padding="0"/>
            <mj-class name="head-text" font-size="36px" font-weight="600"/>
            <mj-class name="product" border-radius="15px"/>
        </mj-attributes>     
</mj-head>



<mj-body>
    <mj-wrapper>
         <mj-section>
              <mj-column width="45%" background-color="#f3f7fd">
                    <mj-image src="https://image.s10.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe3411717064057d731372/m/1/8c5599db-0f74-40e1-8704-5bf6465deb88.png" alt="iphone 13" />
                     <mj-text>
                               <p style="margin:8px">New</p>
                               <p style="margin:8px">iPhone 13</p>
                               <p style="margin:8px 8px 25px">From $799 or $33.29/mo. for 24 mo. <sup>1</sup></p>
                      </mj-text>
              </mj-column>
              <mj-column width="45%" >
                    <mj-table width="100%" border="1px solid red">
                               <tr style="padding-left: 20px">
                                    <td style=" width: 30%; border: 1px solid blue">
                                        <p style="margin:0;">New</p>
                                        <p style="margin:0;">iPhone 13</p>
                                        <p style="margin:0;">Silicone Case</p>
                                        <p style="margin:0;">$49</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid red">
                                        <img style="width: 100px" 
                                         src="https://image.s10.sfmc- content.com/lib/fe3411717064057d731372/m/1/d8c123db-38c2-4e79-b169-e243b320c6a8.png" alt="iphone 13 case"/>
                                    </td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr style="border: 1px solid green" >
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid purple">
                                        <img style="width: 200px;" src="https://image.s10.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe3411717064057d731372/m/1/62b98203-08b0-4974-b1c8-931b2e710b16.png" alt="snowflake magsafe"/>
                                    </td>    
                               </tr>
                   </mj-table>
             </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
    </mj-wrapper>
```

Comment: If you need to use table for the right hand side I'd suggest using it just for the first row and taking the final image outside the table so it can easily span that full column width.

Answer (score 2):

I have not looked at all the things you want to do with the layout, but here is the basic idea to get your elements in the right relationship with one another.

The main change is to take the final image out of the table and put it directly beneath so that it can easily span the full column width.

This code also puts the red phone image in as a background to the table simply because it seemed more natural to do this but of course if img works for you then replace it.

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-wrapper>
         <mj-section>
              <mj-column width="45%" background-color="#f3f7fd">
                    <mj-image src="https://image.s10.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe3411717064057d731372/m/1/8c5599db-0f74-40e1-8704-5bf6465deb88.png" alt="iphone 13" />
                     <mj-text>
                               <p style="margin:8px">New</p>
                               <p style="margin:8px">iPhone 13</p>
                               <p style="margin:8px 8px 25px">From $799 or $33.29/mo. for 24 mo. <sup>1</sup></p>
                      </mj-text>
              </mj-column>
              <mj-column width="45%" >
                    <mj-table width="100%" border="1px solid red">
                               <tr style="padding-left: 20px">
                                    <td style=" width: 60%; border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px;">
                                        <p style="margin:0;">New</p>
                                        <p style="margin:0;">iPhone 13</p>
                                        <p style="margin:0;">Silicone Case</p>
                                        <p style="margin:0;">$49</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid red; background-image: url(https://image.s10.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe3411717064057d731372/m/1/d8c123db-38c2-4e79-b169-e243b320c6a8.png); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">
                                       
                                    </td>
                               </tr>
                   </mj-table>
                    <mj-image src="https://image.s10.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe3411717064057d731372/m/1/62b98203-08b0-4974-b1c8-931b2e710b16.png" />
             </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
    </mj-wrapper>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

Comment: Thanks, It's a good idea. I got the final image in full width. However, the final image's height is greater than its sibling component (which is the table above it). They are supposed to be equal in height, and I cant use any height property like css. Do you have any recommendations?